# Pass int array from controller to script tag in view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller

I need  to pass my int array to a script tag and then put the values in the for loop to use them on the view
Here is my controller action:

```
 public ActionResult Graph2()
        {
            int[] PostIDArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            int[] CommentNumberArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        ViewBag.PostIDArray = PostIDArray;
        ViewBag.CommentNumberArray = CommentNumberArray;
        return View();
    }
```

Here is the script tag in my view:

```
<script>                        
            var freqData = [];            
            var PostIDArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.PostIDrray))            
            var CommentNumberArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CommentNumberArray));

            for (var i = 0; i<8 ; i++) {
                freqData.push({ PostID: PostIDArray[i], Comment: CommentNumberArray[i] });
            }
</script>
```

I can't get the values from the controller to the view. Something is wrong with the ViewBag. I tryed ViewData and didn't work too.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Didn't work, don't see nothing in console

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // number array
    var a = [ @(string.Join(", ", (int[])ViewBag.PostIDArray )) ];
    console.log(a);  // [1, 2, 3...]

    var b = [ @(string.Join(", ", (int[])ViewBag.CommentNumberArray )) ];
    console.log(b);  // [1, 2, 3...]
</script>
```

Comment: Can you write it inside the for loop? it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.PostIDArray" id="PostIDArray" />
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.CommentNumberArray" id="CommentNumberArray" />
```

and the script:

```
<script>
var freqData = [];
var postIDArray = $('#PostIDArray').val().splt(',');
var commentNumberArray = $('#CommentNumberArray').val().split(',');

for (var i = 0; i<8 ; i++) {
   freqData.push({ PostID: postIDArray[i], Comment: commentNumberArray[i] });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Array));
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
   {
        freqData[i] = array[i];
   }
```